# Will an .html file recognize .NET scriptlets or does it have to be convert to an aspx

Tags: javascript, c#, html

I believe that I'm trying something that is not possible, but wanted to make sure.  I'm trying to set a JavaScript variable inside of an html page.  The index.html page to be specific.

I'm doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var theLimit = '<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TheLimit"]%>'</script>
```

Will it be recognized in an html file, or does it need to be converted to an aspx file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML will not process the server-side command "<%", so you will have to change the page to a format that will process it, such as .aspx (not .ashx).

Comment: That's what I figured, but thanks for the confirmation. I must have had ashx on the brain, I'll switch back to aspx.